# Zend Framework 2 session life time

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I am trying to set the max life time of a session with the `\Zend\Session\Container`. To test it I put it to 1 sec.

Now I looked at the [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.session.config.html)

So i did

```
$config = new StandardConfig();
$config->setOptions(array(
    'remember_me_seconds' => 1,
));
$manager = new SessionManager($config);
$session = new Container('user', $manager);
```

But no success. Then I started googling and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774809/how-to-bootstrap-sessions-in-zend-framework-2)

So I made the config to

```
return array(
    'session' => array(
        'remember_me_seconds' => 2419200,
        'use_cookies' => true,
        'cookie_httponly' => true,
    ),
);
```

(the config worked and was loaded into the manager) but again no success

So I continued searching and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567673/zend-session-sessionmanager-and-cookie-lifetime)

But again no success.

So after all the searching I couldn't get it working, so now I hope some one else got it working and can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I finaly found out what the issue was.

The problem was that I used

```
$sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
$sessionConfig->setOptions(array(
    'use_cookies' => true,
    'cookie_httponly' => true,
    'gc_maxlifetime' => $config['authTimeout'],
));
$manager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
```

This "worked" the only issue was that there was set a cookie with the lifetime `session`. This ment different things in browsers. Ie in chrome it is destroyed if you close the tab, so no matter how high the `gc_maxlifetime` it would not work.

So an easy fix would be the following

```
$sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
$sessionConfig->setOptions(array(
    'use_cookies' => true,
    'cookie_httponly' => true,
    'gc_maxlifetime' => $config['authTimeout'],
    'cookie_lifetime' => $config['authTimeout'],
));
$manager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
```

Hope it would help some one in the futue

*`$config['authTimeout']` is a positive integer value*

Answer (score 0):

```
$config = new StandardConfig();
$config->setOptions(array(
    'cookie_lifetime' => '2419200',
    'gc_maxlifetime' => '2419200'
));
```

Change the value of `2419200` to how many seconds you actually want.

Comment: I think I need to set this config to the manager, and then the manager to the Container. If so, it is not working for me. I also tried to change the StandardConfig to SessionConfig

Answer (score 0):

In application global.php or you can do it in module config:

```
 'session_config' => array(
    'name' => 'your session name',
    'remember_me_seconds' => 60 * 60 * 24 * 30*3,
    'use_cookies' => true,
    'cookie_httponly' => true,
),
```

check Zend\Session\Service\SessionConfig.

Comment: You need to use this configuration manually. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774809/how-to-bootstrap-sessions-in-zend-framework-2