# Zend Framework 2 CSRF validation

Tags: php, zend-framework2, csrf

I have application base on Zend framework 2. I have a form with CSRF field. If I fill the form and submit after around 5 minutes it gives me `The form submitted did not originate from the expected site` validation error.

So I assumed it might be some issue with session configurations. Then I added options to `SessionConfig` on `module.config.php` as [follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525329/zend-framework-2-session-life-time)

> ```
> 'session' => array(
>     'remember_me_seconds' => 2419200,
>     'use_cookies' => true,
>     'cookie_httponly' => true,
>     'cookie_lifetime' => '2419200',
>     'gc_maxlifetime' => '2419200'
> ),
> ```

But the problem still exist. Do you know how to fix this issue ?

--Update--

My form class contains the CSRF element as follows,

```
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
        'name' => 'security',
        'options' => array(
            'csrf_options' => array(
                'timeout' => 20000
            )
        )
    ));
```

None of these seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

The Csrf system under ZendFramework configures the session duration from the parameter stored in the configuration of the Csrf element under the `timeout` key as shown in the following example :

```
$form->add([
    'type' => Element\Csrf::class,
    'name' => 'csrf',
    'options' => [
        'csrf_options' => [
            'timeout' => 600,
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Put the session config under the `config` key as shown in the following example :

```
'session' => [
    'config' => [
        'class'   => Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig::class,
        'options' => [
            'name'                => 'SID',
            'use_cookies'         => true,
            'cookie_httponly'     => true,
            'remember_me_seconds' => 2419200,
        ],
    ],
]
```

Comment: Infact I have already done that. I will update the question. Even with timeout it is having the issue.